# Should i send filter with AJAX or filter an array?

Tags: ajax, database, filter

i'm implementing a web page that shows certain rows fetched from a database.
At loading, i make an AJAX request to fetch the rows in a certain range of time(the initial call will take today's rows), and save them in a global variable(e.g "rows").

I have two text field to set the starting and the ending point of my research, and every time i change the value of those text-fields, i make another call to the db to get the new data and update global "rows" variable.

My question is: if i have different text-field filters and sort options that apply filters and sort to the fetched rows, should i make another request to the db(with the selected filters/sort) and let the db handles the filter/sort, or should i apply the filters/sort directly the global "rows" variable?

Of course i think the db filtering and sorting would be more efficient, but the number of rows shouldn't be more than 100, max 200 rows, and i was wondering if it would be worth it to make another AJAX request just for filter the result.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you paging the results from the query, or showing all results?  If you are paging results- it may be more efficient to apply the filtering and sorting directly as part of the db query called by your AJAX request.  If you're showing all results to begin with, applying the filters on the front end without any further ajax result could suffice.

Answer (score 0):

have you try with datatables server side??

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

I think is a good options for you and very easy to implement

Comment: Hi,
as faras i understand, datatables perform a request on every action, rigth? So you suggest to make a request on filtering and sorting action.

Comment: you can perform your request and filtering, if you use the spp class, you can use SSP::complex() to make the personal query